# Keep getting type error with decorative function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I keep getting a type error for this. I am experimenting with decorative functions. Any help is appreciated

```
def primer(func):
    def primes(n):
        print (n)
        return None





@primer
def find_prime(n):
    while True:
        count = 2
        if (count == n):
            z = ("PRIME")
            return z
        elif (n % count == 0):
            z = n / count
            return z
        else:
            count += 1
            continue

prime = find_prime()
prime(10)
```

Comment: Hint: remove anything that is related to decorator and see if you still get error.
Hint 2: Read what's written in that error.
Hint 3: With such approach "Boo boo. HELP!" You're not going far. Research on the internet. Don't be surprised with negative votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def primer(func):
    def primes(n):
        print(n)
        #return None: dont know why this is here, you could do without it
    return primes
    #The nontype error is occuring because your code is returning none
    #so to fix that all you have to do is return the inner function


@primer
def find_prime(n):
    while True:
        count = 2
        if (count == n):
            z = ("PRIME")
            return z
        elif (n % count == 0):
            z = n / count
            return z
        else:
            count += 1
            continue

prime = find_prime
# if you want to turn a function into a variable you have to make sure it's
# callable, which means no parantheses around it

prime(15) # then you can call it
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I feel like a dummy for making all those mistakes.